# react native `TouchableOpacity` in 'absolute' view can not be clickable on android

Tags: expo, react-native, touchableopacity

I'v try to make a `SlectBox` with react native.

To make that dropdown menu can be floated, I gava an `absolute` position to wrapper `View`, then make a clickable component with `TouchableOpacity` inside that `View`. It works well on `Ios` and `Web`, but not on `android`. There were many solutions on google like reordering component or give a `zIndex` to `WrapperView` or use `Pressable` etc.., but I could not find proper solution for my case.

Belows are my whole code. and You can test this code [here](https://github.com/dooboolab/dooboo-ui/pull/73).

Thank you in advance.

```
import {
  Animated,
  Easing,
  Platform,
  StyleProp,
  TextStyle,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  ViewStyle,
} from 'react-native';
import {DoobooTheme, light, useTheme} from '../theme';
import React, {FC, ReactElement, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';

import {Icon} from '../Icon';
import {Typography} from '../Typography';
import styled from '@emotion/native';
import {withTheme} from '@emotion/react';

const Title = styled.View`
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-width: 1px;

  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

const Item = styled.View`
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;

  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;

type Styles = {
  titleContainer?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  titleText?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  rightElementContainer?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  itemContainer?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  itemText?: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
};
interface ItemCompProps {
  value: string;
  order: number;
  styles?: Styles;
  setIsOpened: (value: boolean) => void;
  itemActiveOpacity: number;
  onPress?: (i: number) => void;
}

const ItemComp: FC<ItemCompProps> = ({
  value,
  order,
  styles,
  setIsOpened,
  itemActiveOpacity,
  onPress,
}) => {
  const {theme} = useTheme();

  const handlePress = (): void => {
    onPress?.(order);
    setIsOpened(false);
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress} activeOpacity={itemActiveOpacity}>
      <Item
        style={[
          {
            borderColor: theme.primary,
            backgroundColor: theme.textContrast,
          },
          styles?.itemContainer,
        ]}>
        <Typography.Body2 style={styles?.itemText}>{value}</Typography.Body2>
      </Item>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

interface Props {
  data: string[];
  onPress?: (i: number) => void;
  selectedIndex?: number;
  theme?: DoobooTheme;
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  styles?: Styles;
  rotateDuration?: number;
  titleActiveOpacity?: number;
  itemActiveOpacity?: number;
  isRotate?: boolean;
  rightElement?: ReactElement | null;
}

const Component: FC<Props> = ({
  data,
  onPress,
  selectedIndex = 0,
  style,
  styles,
  rotateDuration = 200,
  titleActiveOpacity = 1,
  itemActiveOpacity = 1,
  isRotate: shouldRotate = true,
  rightElement = <Icon name="chevron-down-light" />,
}) => {
  const {theme} = useTheme();
  const [isOpened, setIsOpened] = useState(false);

  const rotateAnimValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  useEffect(() => {
    const toValue = isOpened ? 1 : 0;

    if (!shouldRotate) rotateAnimValue.setValue(toValue);

    Animated.timing(rotateAnimValue, {
      toValue,
      duration: rotateDuration,
      easing: Easing.linear,
      useNativeDriver: Platform.OS !== 'web' ? true : false,
    }).start();
  }, [isOpened, rotateAnimValue, rotateDuration, shouldRotate]);

  return (
    <View style={[style]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => setIsOpened((prev) => !prev)}
        activeOpacity={titleActiveOpacity}>
        <Title
          style={[
            {
              borderColor: theme.primary,
              backgroundColor: theme.textContrast,
            },
            styles?.titleContainer,
          ]}>
          <Typography.Body2 style={styles?.titleText} testID="selected-value">
            {data[selectedIndex]}
          </Typography.Body2>
          {rightElement ? (
            <Animated.View
              style={[
                {
                  position: 'absolute',
                  right: 10,
                  transform: [
                    {
                      rotate: rotateAnimValue.interpolate({
                        inputRange: [0, 1],
                        outputRange: ['0deg', '180deg'],
                      }),
                    },
                  ],
                },
                styles?.rightElementContainer,
              ]}>
              {rightElement}
            </Animated.View>
          ) : null}
        </Title>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
          {isOpened &&
            data.map((datum, key) => (
              <ItemComp
                key={key}
                order={key}
                value={datum}
                styles={styles}
                setIsOpened={setIsOpened}
                onPress={onPress}
                itemActiveOpacity={itemActiveOpacity}
              />
            ))}
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

Component.defaultProps = {theme: light};

export const SelectBox = withTheme(Component);
```

**My solution**

I resolved this problem with `react-native-gesture-handler`. :)
Install `react-native-gesture-handler`, then using `TouchableOpacity` from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to render out the component you want to be on top of stack below the component you want to bring below it

**How I solve this issue:**
I was implementing custom dynamic toaster using context to use it globally and wasn't able to access touchable opacity due to absolute positioning but i realized i was rendering my Toaster component before my main Stack Navigator which was bringing my toaster below navigation layer so i rendered it after stack navigator and it worked

**BEFORE:**

```js
 <ToasterContext.Provider value={{toasts:this.state.toastState, showToaster: this.showToaster,closeToaster: this.closeToaster }}>
      <Provider store={store.store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={store.persistor}>
         {toastState.length > 0 
            && toastState.length <= 3 
            && toastState.map((t, i) => {
                return(
                  <DynamicToast i={i} key={i} t={t} position={"bottom"} duration={4000} closeToaster={this.closeToaster} />
                )
              }
            )} 
          <NetworkConnectionModal/>
          <AppContainer /> // I was rendering before my AppContainer
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
 </ToasterContext.Provider>
```

**AFTER: (Resolved my problem)**

```js
 <ToasterContext.Provider value={{toasts:this.state.toastState, showToaster: this.showToaster,closeToaster: this.closeToaster }}>
      <Provider store={store.store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={store.persistor}>
          <NetworkConnectionModal/>
          <AppContainer />
          {toastState.length > 0 
            && toastState.length <= 3 
            && toastState.map((t, i) => {
                return(
                  <DynamicToast i={i} key={i} t={t} position={"bottom"} duration={4000} closeToaster={this.closeToaster} />
                )
              }
            )} 
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
 </ToasterContext.Provider>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. But I'm little confused how can I apply your solution.

Comment: Which touchable opacity is not working one in ItemComp or one in Component?

Comment: Opps! It's In`ItemComp` :)

Answer (score 0):

Most of this is because the element is hidden behind other elements after absolute positioning.

Just like the picture in PPT is set to the bottom, but in some cases in HTML, you can still see your element. In this case, we need to set this element to the top.

Open the developer tool, select your element, add a Z-index to the element style of this element, and increase from 2 to see which value can just select your element. After confirmation, add a style to the project file.

```
z-index: 2,//add this to your component style
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do that like you said, but it doesn't work as I wish. I solve this problem with `react-native-gesture-handler`. :)